Proability of measuing a qubit in a two qubit system without having a perpendicular basis
I am trying to understand how to apply Born's rule on two qubit systems.
From class, the teacher told us that we can write the state like so:

only if $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ are ortogonal.
But now my quesition is what happens when they are not?
Take for instance $|\phi\rangle = \dfrac 1 2 |1\rangle|{\psi}\rangle - \dfrac 1 2|1\rangle U |\psi\rangle  $ where $U$ is a unitary gate.
What is the probability of measuing $\phi$ in the state $|1\rangle$?
Because $|\psi\rangle$ and $U |\psi\rangle$ might not be orthogonal I am a bit stuck..
From the homework answers I kindof know that the probability should be equal to


Lets presume your example is correct then the give homework answer follows from the example.
Born's rule in quantum mechanics is a fundamental principle used to calculate the probability of measuring a particular state. For a quantum state represented by a vector $\psi \rangle $, the probability of finding the system in a particular state $| \phi \rangle $ upon measurement is given by the square of the absolute value of the inner product of $| \phi \rangle $ and $ | \psi \rangle $, i.e.,
$
P = |\langle \phi | \psi \rangle|^2
$
You mentioned a state $ | \phi \rangle = \frac{1}{2} |1\rangle |\psi\rangle - \frac{1}{2} |1\rangle U|\psi\rangle $ where $ U $ is a unitary operation. To simplify, let's denote:

$ | \psi' \rangle = U | \psi \rangle $

Given the unitary nature of $ U $, $ | \psi \rangle $ and $ | \psi' \rangle $ are generally not orthogonal unless specifically designed or stated.
You want to find the probability of measuring $ | \phi \rangle $ in the state $ |1\rangle $. According to quantum mechanics, we first project $ | \phi \rangle $ onto $ |1\rangle $ and then apply Born's rule. Let's break it down:
The projection of $ | \phi \rangle $ onto $ |1\rangle $ involves only considering the terms in $ | \phi \rangle $ that include $ |1\rangle $. This yields:
$
| \text{Projected } \phi \rangle = \frac{1}{2} |\psi \rangle - \frac{1}{2} |\psi' \rangle
$
Now, the probability of measuring $ |1\rangle $ in the state $ | \phi \rangle $ is the norm squared of the projected state:
$
P = \left\| \frac{1}{2} |\psi \rangle - \frac{1}{2} |\psi' \rangle \right\|^2
$
Expanding this, we use the properties of the inner product and the unitarity of $ U $:
$
P = \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 \left( \langle \psi | - \langle \psi' | \right) \left( |\psi \rangle - |\psi' \rangle \right)
$
$
P = \frac{1}{4} \left( \langle \psi | \psi \rangle - \langle \psi | \psi' \rangle - \langle \psi' | \psi \rangle + \langle \psi' | \psi' \rangle \right)
$
Since $ U $ is unitary, $ \langle \psi | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi' | \psi' \rangle = 1 $, and $ \langle \psi | \psi' \rangle = \langle \psi' | \psi \rangle = c $, where $ c $ is generally complex. Thus,
$
P = \frac{1}{4} (2 - c - c^*)
$
To fill in $ c $ into the formula for the probability $ P $, we first need to understand that $ c $ is the complex inner product between $ | \psi \rangle $ and $ U | \psi \rangle $. Let's denote this inner product as:
$ c = \langle \psi | U | \psi \rangle $
This value represents the overlap between $ | \psi \rangle $ and its transformed state $ U | \psi \rangle $. Because $ U $ is a unitary operation, both $ | \psi \rangle $ and $ U | \psi \rangle $ are normalized states, but they may not be orthogonal.
the formula for $ P $ in terms of $ c $ is given by:
$ P = \frac{1}{4} (2 - c - c^*) $
Here $ c^* $ is the complex conjugate of $ c $. The terms $ c $ and $ c^* $ are generally complex numbers and their subtraction $ c + c^* $ yields $ 2 \operatorname{Re}(c) $, where $ \operatorname{Re}(c) $ denotes the real part of $ c $. Therefore, the formula simplifies to:
$ P = \frac{1}{4} (2 - 2 \operatorname{Re}(c)) $
$ P = \frac{1}{2} (1 - \operatorname{Re}(c)) $

Thank you for your answer, I now understand better.
I am a bit confused about the fact that you are using the norm of other states when using the Born Rule.
In class we learned that we sum the squared magnitude of the amplitudes for the states in the projected state.  How does the probablity work when c is a complex number? I do not know how to interpret a probability that is a complex number...
